# PHP file_get_contents returns "1" and fails with request headers

Tags: php, return, fopen, file-get-contents

I have a php file `fopen.php` that retrieves data from another php file `d.php` with a GET request e.g. `d.php?p=4`

When I run this code I'm getting weird results. It works on my local server but not on the heartinternet one that this website is running on

`fopen.php?p=4`

```
echo $_GET['p']."<br/>";

if (!file_exists("d.php")) { 
    die('File does not exist');
}
else
{
    echo file_get_contents("d.php") or die("FAIL");
    echo "<br/>";
    echo file_get_contents(("d.php?p=".$_GET['p'])) or die("FAIL");
}
```

This page reads as follows:

```
4
1
FAIL
```

allow_url_fopen is On

Any clues as to what might be happening?

Comment: `d.php?=4` isn't a valid URL. Typo?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the full URL (including http://) if you want to initiate a GET request with file_get_contents.

Answer (score 0):

By requesting `d.php?p=4`, you're supposed using HTTP(s) request, so It's required a full URL. It's weird that your code working in local server.

Btw, you may using it wrong, any HTTP request should be used for connecting to external resource, in this case, you just need some kind of local including.
Ex:

```
else
{
    //echo file_get_contents("d.php") or die("FAIL");
    //echo "<br/>";
    //echo file_get_contents(("d.php?p=".$_GET['p'])) or die("FAIL");
    $p = $_GET['p'];
    include 'd.php';
}
```

And on your `d.php`, instead of extracting $_GET['p'], you can directly use the `$p` variable declared on the above code block